# How to apply search to the list in the MVVM (WPF) without recalling the list values every time?

Tags: c#, wpf, search, mvvm, propertychanged

First of all I'm new to the MVVM though in case I'm missing the point please feel free to corect me.

I'm working on the WPF application where I'm using the MVVM Community Toolkit. My application architecture looks more like this:

1. I have  simple `Model` containing  some basic properties

```c#
public class Package : ObservableObject
    {
        private string id;
        public string Id
        {
            get => id;
            set => SetProperty(ref id, value);
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
        }

        private string version;
        public string Version
        {
            get => version;
            set => SetProperty(ref version, value);
        }

        private string summary;
        public string Summary
        {
            get => summary;
            set => SetProperty(ref summary, value);
        }
}
```

2. There is `ViewModel` where there is  `IList<Package>` property and a `AsyncRelayCommand` which calls the process, get output and update the property.

```c#
class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public AsyncRelayCommand StartProcessCommand { get; }
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            
            StartProcessCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(StartProcess, CanStartProcess);
            
        }
        
        private async Task StartProcess()
        {
            
           //Start process, collect the output and set the PackageList property
        }

        private IList<Package> packagesList;

        public IList<Package> PackagesList
        {
            get => packagesList;
            set => SetProperty(ref packagesList, value);
        }
 }
```

3. Then there is a `View` where the binding is done as below:

```c#
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PackagesList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
               
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Version" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Version}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Summary" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Summary}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

and the button to call the RelayCommand (async).

**Here is the question and the problem I'm facing**

I would like to apply the Search `TextBox` to dynamically search the result of the `IList<Package>`, for this purpose I have create a `SearchText` in the `ViewModel` which updates the `IList<Package>` property on the `PropertyChanged` event. The problem is that my property is changing and I would like to ***not recall*** it every time from the process.

1. Create a list
2. Search the list and present it in a View
3. In case I'm removing my searchText value it's still showing the list from the point 1

What will be best approach to achieve this?

**This is so far where I got to but works only once, filter the list but not returning to previous list:**

```c#
public void SearchItem()
        {
            PackagesList = packagesList.Where(package => package.Id == SearchText).ToList();

        }

private string? searchText;
        public string? SearchText
        {
            get => searchText;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref searchText, value);
                SearchItem();
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Please try to keep question with minimal lines.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Create an `IList<Package>` and call it `ResultList` or anything. Set your `ItemsSource` binding to the `ResultList` instead. Anytime you set your `PackagesList`, you set the `ResultList` as well. Now when it gets to the search, you do something of this sort `ResultList = packagesList.Where(package => package.Id == SearchText).ToList();`

Comment: @Jeffery Thank you for this advise. This has solved the problem!

Comment: @user8909887 I'm posting it as an answer. Mark it as an answer to help others as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `MainWindowViewModel` create another property `IList<Package>` and call it `ResultList`

```
    private IList<Package> ResultList { get; set;} // Add Result list
    private IList<Package> packagesList;

    public IList<Package> PackagesList
    {
        get => packagesList;
        set => SetProperty(ref packagesList, value);
    }
```

Set your ItemsSource binding to the `ResultList` instead.

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ResultList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
           
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Version" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Version}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Summary" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Summary}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Anytime you set your `PackagesList`, you set the `ResultList` as well. Now when it gets to the search, you do something of this sort

```
public void SearchItem()
{
    ResultList = packagesList.Where(package => package.Id == SearchText).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your claim, you want to show all the data after deleting the text?
If so, you can try this

```
public void SearchItem()
{   
    PackagesList = packagesList.Where(package => package.Id == SearchText || null == SearchText).ToList();
}
```